# What is the correct format of a SOAP response

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, soapui

I'm working with a Web Service that i didn't make and i'm getting two different responses from the same method, data is the same but format changes and that crashes my app

Response 1:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=...>
<SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="..." xmlns:NS1="..." xmlns:NS2="...">
  <NS1:...>
<return href="#1"/>
  </NS1:...>
<NS2:..." xsi:type="NS2:...">    
</NS2:...>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response 2:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=...>
<SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="..." xmlns:NS1="..." xmlns:NS2="...">
<NS1:...>    
<NS2:..." xsi:type="NS2:...">    
</NS2:...>
<return href="#1"/>
</NS1:...>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The only diference are this lines

```
<return href="#1"/>
</NS1:...>
```

When I get the second one I cannot read the data, so my question is: Is the second way wrong?

EDIT:

This is the error message i get

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: El servidor no puede procesar la       
solicitud.
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error en el documento XML (2, 3726). --->   
System.InvalidOperationException: No se encontró en el documento el elemento con id '2' 
al que se hace referencia.
en System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.GetTarget(String id)
en System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.FixupArrayRefs(Object fixup)
en System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.DoFixups()
en System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadReferencedElements()
```

it says "Can't find the element with id 2"

the second response was made because `UTF8InHeader = TRUE` anyway I'm curious about if it is a valid soap response

Comment: What library are you using, what error are you getting? It also helps if you include the full SOAP output.

Comment: i've added the error i get, but my question is if is correct or acceptable the second response format. As you can see in the first one the structure is <NS1><NS1/><NS2><NS2/> and in the other is <NS1> <NS2> <NS2/> <NS1/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer would be in the WSDL for this service. That is the "contract" with the outside world.